# Multiple grouping in angular datatable

Tags: angularjs, datatable, datatables

I am trying to perform multiple grouping in my data tables, I can manage to group by one column thanks to this example.

https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html

Does anybody know about any plugin that works with angular and angularDatables (https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome) to group the data by more than one column?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of anybody was having the same problem, the only thing I did to the code provided in https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html, was to use the same code for every column I wanted to group.

```
api.column(0 { page: 'current' })
.data()
                            .each(function(group, i) {
                                if (last !== group) {
                                    $(rows)
                                        .eq(i)
                                        .before(
                                            '<tr class="group"><td colspan="5">' + group + '</td></tr>'
                                        );
                                    last = group;
                                }
                            });
api.column(1 { page: 'current' })
.data()
                            .each(function(group, i) {
                                if (last !== group) {
                                    $(rows)
                                        .eq(i)
                                        .before(
                                            '<tr class="group"><td colspan="5">' + group + '</td></tr>'
                                        );
                                    last = group;
                                }
                            });
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on @Martha's answer, it works also for angular 5 in this way:

```
    var groupColumn = 1;

    this.dtOptions = {
     // pagingType: 'full_numbers',
      pageLength: 10,
      responsive: true,
      language: { search: "" },
      order:[1,'desc'],
      columnDefs: [
                      { type: 'date-uk', targets: 1}  // specifying date format
                  ],
      drawCallback: function ( settings ) {
            var api = this.api();
            var rows = api.rows( {page:'current'} ).nodes();
            var last=null; 
            api.column(groupColumn, {page:'current'} ).data().each( function ( group, i ) {
                if ( last !== group ) {
                    $(rows).eq( i ).before(
                        '<tr style="background-color:#dedede" class="group"><th colspan="5">'+group+'</th></tr>'
                    ); 
                    last = group;
                }
            });
        }
    };
```